# Mi android manifest.xml no reconoce los permisos

Tags: flutter

I have an app that uses a qrscan to obtain data and then does a service with the scanned data, the first time I tested it on a Redmi 9 if it asked for later permissions with other devices it no longer asked me for permissions, asking for the correct functioning of the library
this is my manifest:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app_roja_rastreo_update">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <application
        android:label="app_roja_rastreo_update"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Try to use permission_handler in my code, to force the user to activate the permissions
but the console gave me this:

```
V/BoostFramework(28768): mAcquireFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquire(int,int[])
V/BoostFramework(28768): mReleaseFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockRelease()
V/BoostFramework(28768): mAcquireTouchFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquireTouch(android.view.MotionEvent,android.util.DisplayMetrics,int,int[])
V/BoostFramework(28768): mIOPStart method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStart(int,java.lang.String)
V/BoostFramework(28768): mIOPStop method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStop()
V/BoostFramework(28768): BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@4363c91
50
D/permissions_handler(28768): No permissions found in manifest for: []2
```

my code with the use of permission handler

```
  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return GestureDetector(
     onTap: () async {
       var status = await Permission.camera.status;
       //await Permission.contacts.request();
       if(status.isDenied|| status.isRestricted||status.isPermanentlyDenied){
         await Permission.contacts.request();
       }
       if (await Permission.contacts.request().isGranted) {
         processQuery(context, await getCode());
       }
     },
     child: Container(
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
           color: Colors.blue.shade700,
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
       width: 60,
       height: 60,
       child: Icon(
         Icons.qr_code,
         color: Colors.white,
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
```